# potential leak? - analyzer

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c

analyze state leak problem, why?

```
+ (DebugOutput *) sharedDebug
    {
      @synchronized(self)
      {
        if (sharedDebugInstance == nil)
        {
          [[self alloc] init];
        }  
      }
      return sharedDebugInstance;
    }
```

Comment: I always wonder why such questions are tagged as C...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well sharedDebugInstance is not assigned, you probably wanted to do that:

```
sharedDebugInstance = [[self alloc] init];
```

Comment: have a look to this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like